# Multi-region Artifactory server on-prem

Tags: artifactory

Is it possible to run Artifactory on-prem server across multiple AWS regions with a single accessible url?

Comment: It's possible, but a complex and fragile setup. Also requires an enterprise license. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: our infrastructure is Multi region, but we rely on Artifactory only in one region, so if the region that Artifactory is in out, then we have a problem.

Comment: Looks like you got a good answer below. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal you should think about Artifactory SaaS solution.

Otherwise yes, you can have a multi-region solution with several Artifactory instances communicating with each other via federation, but it isn't the same thing.

Here's some documentation about it:

https://jfrog.com/blog/our-solution-for-scalable-multi-region-saas-deployment/

https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/replication-using-artifactory-to-manage-binaries-across-multi-site-topologies/

https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-configure-federated-repositories/

Comment: I can't use SaaS Solution.

Comment: Ok, so if you want to increase the availability of artifacts in a multi-site environment you just have to think about federation. If you are thinking of a "single" installation, it's certainly not recommended to split the nodes of an Artifactory installation into different Regions, as performance could be affected.